# Strcmp no me funciona correctamente

Tags: c++, eclipse, sqlite3

Estoy trabajando en un programa donde necesitas inciar sesión. Para eso tengo el metodo iniciar sesión, el cual mediante cin>> recibe una contraseña y un dni. Después, usando ese dni crea un usuario vacio que lo llenara con los datos recogidos de la base de datos. Hasta ahi funciona bien, recoge los datos y rellena bien el usuario. El problema es cuando a la hora de comparar entre la contraseña metida y la contraseña recibida del usuario recogido de la base de datos me dice que no son iguales, a pesar de que usando el cout para comprobar estas me salen identicas.

La funcion de iniciar sesion:

```
void loggearse(sqlite3 *db) {
    char *dni = new char[9];
    cout << "Introduzca su DNI: ";
    cin >> dni;

    char *contrasenya = new char[32];
    cout << "Introduzca su contrasenya: ";
    cin >> contrasenya;

    Usuario u;
    inicioSesion(db, dni, &u);

    cout<<endl<<u.getContrasenya()<<" "<<contrasenya<<endl;
    if (strcmp(u.getContrasenya(), contrasenya)) {
        inicioUsuario(&u, db);
    } else {
        cout << "Contraseña o usuario inexistente por favor intentelo de nuevo"<<endl;
        loggearse(db);
    }
}
```

La funcion de recoger el usuario:

```
int inicioSesion(sqlite3 *db, char *dni, Usuario *usuario) {
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    char sql[] = "SELECT * FROM USUARIO WHERE DNI = ?";

    int resultado = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, strlen(sql), &stmt, NULL);
    if (resultado != SQLITE_OK) {
        cout << "Error preparando la declaración (SELECT)" << endl
                << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << endl;
        return resultado;
    }

    resultado = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, dni, strlen(dni), SQLITE_STATIC);
    if (resultado != SQLITE_OK) {
        cout << "Error uniendo el parametro id" << endl << sqlite3_errmsg(db)
                << endl;
        return resultado;
    }

    resultado = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    if (resultado == SQLITE_ROW) {
        usuario->apellido =
                new char[sizeof((char*) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2)) + 1];
        usuario->contrasenya = new char[sizeof((char*) sqlite3_column_text(stmt,
                5)) + 1];
        usuario->dni =
                new char[sizeof((char*) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0)) + 1];
        usuario->matricula = new char[sizeof((char*) sqlite3_column_text(stmt,
                7)) + 1];
        usuario->nombre = new char[sizeof((char*) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1))
                + 1];
        usuario->tarjeta = 0;
        usuario->tipo = new char[sizeof((char*) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 6))
                + 1];
        usuario->telefono = 0;

        usuario->setdni((char*) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0));
        usuario->setNombre((char*) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1));
        usuario->setApellido((char*) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2));
        usuario->telefono = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 3);
        usuario->tarjeta = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 4);
        usuario->setContrasenya((char*) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 5));
        usuario->setTipo((char*) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 6));
        usuario->setMatricula((char*) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 7));
    }

    resultado = sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

    if (resultado != SQLITE_OK) {
        cout << "Error terminando la declaracion (SELECT)" << endl
                << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << endl;
        return resultado;
    }

    return SQLITE_OK;
}
```

Comment: Una pista... ¿Qué ocurre si pones una contraseña que no es correcta? strcmp devuelve 0 si las cadenas son iguales

Comment: @Luis he añadido un == 0 en el if y ya funciona, muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Al ver tu código he tenido un escalofrío que ha recorrido mi espina dorsal hasta llegar a mi cráneo y darme una jaqueca tremenda y un infartito.

Me ha chocado mucho que hayas redactado un código con una apariencia tan limpia y pulcra mientras que a la vez no hayas seguido las buenas prácticas mínimas que se esperan de un código en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

## La memoria que se pide con `new` **DEBE** borrarse con `delete`.

Estás pidiendo memoria dinámica para leer el DNI y la contraseña. Esto, además de innecesario es incorrecto, pues no borras esa memoria; tienes que hacer esto:

```
void loggearse(sqlite3 *db) {
    char *dni = new char[9];
    cout << "Introduzca su DNI: ";
    cin >> dni;

    char *contrasenya = new char[32];
    cout << "Introduzca su contrasenya: ";
    cin >> contrasenya;

    Usuario u;
    inicioSesion(db, dni, &u);

    cout<<endl<<u.getContrasenya()<<" "<<contrasenya<<endl;
    if (strcmp(u.getContrasenya(), contrasenya)) {
        inicioUsuario(&u, db);
    } else {
        cout << "Contraseña o usuario inexistente por favor intentelo de nuevo"<<endl;
        loggearse(db);
    }

    delete[] dni;         // Hay que borrar la memoria dinámica que se solicita
    delete[] contrasenya; // de lo contrario tendrás fugas de memoria.
}
```

Mejor aún, no uses memoria dinámica; en su lugar usa un objeto `std::string`:

```
void loggearse(sqlite3 *db) {
    string dni;
    cout << "Introduzca su DNI: ";
    cin >> dni;

    string contrasenya;
    cout << "Introduzca su contrasenya: ";
    cin >> contrasenya;

    Usuario u;
    inicioSesion(db, dni.c_str(), &u);
//                       ^^^^^^^ <-- Tratar el string como formación de caracteres

    cout<<endl<<u.getContrasenya()<<" "<<contrasenya<<endl;
    if (strcmp(u.getContrasenya(), contrasenya)) {
        inicioUsuario(&u, db);
    } else {
        cout << "Contraseña o usuario inexistente por favor intentelo de nuevo"<<endl;
        loggearse(db);
    }
}
```

Dicho esto, `strcmp` funciona correctamente "[*SELECT isn't broken*](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/)", esa función compara numéricamente (usando el valor ASCII de las letras de la cadena) dos cadenas y devuelve un valor menor a cero cuando la primera es menor a la segunda, un valor mayor a cero en caso contrario y cero si ambas son iguales. Puedes leer la documentación de dicha función [aquí](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp).

Si en lugar de confiar en esa función de las cabeceras de [c](/questions/tagged/c) confiases en las herramientas del lenguaje C++, podrías comparar dos cadenas usando el operador de igualdad (`==`).

Así que, si `Usuario::getContrasenya()` devolviese un `std::string` tu código podría haber sido así:

```
void loggearse(sqlite3 *db) {
    string dni;
    cout << "Introduzca su DNI: ";
    cin >> dni;

    string contrasenya;
    cout << "Introduzca su contrasenya: ";
    cin >> contrasenya;

    Usuario u;
    inicioSesion(db, dni.c_str(), &u);
//                       ^^^^^^^ <-- Tratar el string como formación de caracteres

    cout<<endl<<u.getContrasenya()<<" "<<contrasenya<<endl;
    if (u.getContrasenya() == contrasenya) {
//                         ^^ <-- Sencillo e intuitivo.
        inicioUsuario(&u, db);
    } else {
        cout << "Contraseña o usuario inexistente por favor intentelo de nuevo"<<endl;
        loggearse(db);
    }
}
```